# Obtener id de un registro al presionar un botón con AJAX, js vanilla, php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

[image: iImagen de la tabla]

Tengo la siguiente tabla, esta al presionar el botón "eliminar" debe entrar a una función de `js` (eso lo hace bien), sin embargo, necesito capturar el numero de registro que sale en la tabla, por ejemplo el #123.

Cómo podría hacerlo?

Cabe destacar, que la tabla está hecha con `ajax`, por lo que cada vez que ingreso un registro, se añade ahí y aparece por correspondencia un nuevo boton de eliminar.

**Nota:** No puedo utilizar `jquery`.

```
<?php
require_once("conexion.php"); 

$columns=['IDE_REGISTRO','TIP_IDENTIFICACION', 'NUM_IDENTIFICACION', 'DSC_NOMBRE', 'DSC_APELLIDOS', 'IND_SEXO', 'FEC_NACIMIENTO', 'DSC_LUGAR', 'DSC_NACIONALIDAD', 'IND_ESTADO', 'DSC_TELEFONO', 'DSC_EMAIL', 'DSC_DOMICILIO', 'IND_PROVINCIA'];
$table = "curriculum";

$sql ="SELECT  ". implode(",", $columns) . "
FROM $table";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
$num_rows = $resultado->num_rows;

$html='';

if($num_rows > 0){
while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
    $html.='<tr>';
    $id_reg=$row['IDE_REGISTRO'];
    echo=$id_reg;
    $html.='<th>'.$row['IDE_REGISTRO'].'</th>';
    $html.='<th>'.$row['TIP_IDENTIFICACION'].'</th>';
    $html.='<th>'.$row['NUM_IDENTIFICACION'].'</th>';
    $html.='<th>'.$row['DSC_NOMBRE'].'</th>';
    $html.='<th>'.$row['DSC_APELLIDOS'].'</th>';
    $html.='<th>'.$row['IND_SEXO'].'</th>';
    $html.='<th>'.$row['FEC_NACIMIENTO'].'</th>';
    $html.='<th>'.$row['DSC_LUGAR'].'</th>';
    $html.='<th>'.$row['DSC_NACIONALIDAD'].'</th>';
    $html.='<th>'.$row['IND_ESTADO'].'</th>';
    $html.='<th>'.$row['DSC_TELEFONO'].'</th>';
    $html.='<th>'.$row['DSC_EMAIL'].'</th>';
    $html.='<th>'.$row['DSC_DOMICILIO'].'</th>';
    $html.='<th>'.$row['IND_PROVINCIA'].'</th>';
    $html.='<th><button type="button" onClick="eliminar();"> Eliminar </th>';
    $html.='<tr>';
}
}else{
    $html.='<tr>';
    $html.='<th colspan="7">Sin resultados</th>';
    $html.='</tr>';
}

echo $html

?>
<script src="js.js"></script>
```

Comment: Recuerda que debes publicar en la pregunta un bloque de código mínimo para reproducir el escenario. Así es más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: @DjCrazy acabo de añadir código, para ver si puedo explicarme mejor, soy algo nuevo en esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el momento de maquetar cada `<tr>` puedes pasarle una función al botón para que se ejecute al escuchar el evento `onclick` y a esa función le pasas el id del registro como parámetro.

```
$html.='<th><button type="button" onClick="eliminar('.$row['IDE_REGISTRO'].');"> Eliminar </th>';
```

Luego en `JS` envías al backend el parámetro recibido.

```js
function eliminar(idRegistro) {
  //Aquí se hace toda la lógica de ajax para enviar al backend el idRegistro
  console.log("Eliminando el registro "+idRegistro);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="eliminar(123)">Eliminar</button>
<button onclick="eliminar(124)">Eliminar</button>
<button onclick="eliminar(125)">Eliminar</button>
<button onclick="eliminar(126)">Eliminar</button>
```

Comment: Entiendo, pero no sé si me falta un poco de lógica, acabo de agregar el código php donde itero para recibir los registros de la base de datos, me puedes ayudar a como pasarle el parametro del id al js?, ya que este id se obtiene desde base de datos

Comment: gracias, hermano, me funcionó

Comment: Justo en el último `<th>` donde tienes la maquetación del botón. Ya tienes la función, lo único que falta es pasarle el id como parámetro. Edité la respuesta para mostrarte cómo debes asignarle el parámetro.

Comment: Si la respuesta te resultó útil, te sugiero marcarla con el check y con el upvote que están al lado izquierdo, de esta manera servirá de referencia para futuros visitantes y ambos ganamos reputación en la comunidad.